# JavaScript - Highlight an element on Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write a JavaScript which will highlight an element in the DOM when the user hovers over it. This is supposed to be a cross-browser external plug-in. Ideally, i'm trying to mimic the behaviour of the browser inspector tools.

I can't say I have no success, but I am stuck with two options, both with its own pros and cons.

**Approach 1**

I handle the `mouseover` event and simply add a border to the target element. When I hover on another element, I just reset the existing highlighted elements. The code for the same is below:

```
function addHighlight(target) {
    target.classList.add('highlighted');
}

function removeHighlight(target) {
    target.classList.remove('highlighted');
}

window.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e) {
    addHighlight(e.target);
});

window.addEventListener('mouseout',function(e) {
    removeHighlight(e.target);
});
```

[Working Example here](http://jsbin.com/dakisad/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

**Pros with this Approach**

It works absolutely fine.

**Cons with this approach**

As I'm adding a border to existing DOM elements, it sort of re-arranges the elements on the page, and you can observe a slight shuffling effect of the elements. Doesn't look great.

**Approach 2**

I wanted the highlighting to be seamless. That is, preserving the look of the page and simply overlaying a highlight mask on top of the element.

TO do this, in the `mouseover` event, I dynamically created a mask element, whose `position` is set to `absolute` and its co-ordinates set to the exact co-ordinates of the target element. Below is my code:

```
window.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e) {
    applyMask(e.target);
});

function applyMask(target) {
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('highlight-wrap').length > 0) {
        resizeMask(target);
    }else{
        createMask(target);
    }
}

function resizeMask(target) {
    var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var hObj = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight-wrap')[0];
    hObj.style.top=rect.top+"px";
    hObj.style.width=rect.width+"px";
    hObj.style.height=rect.height+"px";
    hObj.style.left=rect.left+"px";
   // hObj.style.WebkitTransition='top 0.2s';
}

function createMask(target) {
    var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var hObj = document.createElement("div");
    hObj.className = 'highlight-wrap';
    hObj.style.position='absolute';
    hObj.style.top=rect.top+"px";
    hObj.style.width=rect.width+"px";
    hObj.style.height=rect.height+"px";
    hObj.style.left=rect.left+"px";
    hObj.style.backgroundColor = '#205081';
    hObj.style.opacity='0.5';
    hObj.style.cursor='default';
    //hObj.style.WebkitTransition='top 0.2s';
    document.body.appendChild(hObj);
}

function clearMasks() {
    var hwrappersLength = document.getElementsByClassName("highlight-wrap").length;
    var hwrappers = document.getElementsByClassName("highlight-wrap");
    if(hwrappersLength > 0) {
        for(var i=0; i<hwrappersLength; i++) {
            console.log("Removing existing wrap");
            hwrappers[i].remove();
        }
    }
}
```

[Working example here](http://jsbin.com/rewahag/edit?html,css,js,output)

**Pros with this approach**
I feel this is more elegant, and doesn't disturb the page, just overlays a mask on top of elements.

**Cons**

When the user hovers over the top most container (`div`), it creates a mask for that element. After that, all the subsequent `mouseover` events are ignored, as they are registered on the ***mask***, and not on the actual underlying elements. 
I need to figure out a way around this.

Can anyone help me better Approach 2? Or suggest another approach?

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: _“As I'm adding a border to existing DOM elements, it sort of re-arranges the elements on the page, and you can observe a slight shuffling effect of the elements.”_ - use an `outline` instead of a border.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@LouieAlmeda's answer is the way to go

But if you want to keep the mask div you can do : http://jsbin.com/filelavegu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

the only difference with your is that I added

```
hObj.style.pointerEvents='none';
```

at the mask creation

It makes the pointerevent pass through the div

Comment: I would go ahead with this approach, but I do not want the 'click' events to be registered on my underlying elements. I added e.preventDefault() to my click event listener, but it wouldn't work. I've updated the fiddle, could you please tel me how???

Comment: @sriramsridharan can you please try to reformulate your comments I can't understand it :/ (the problem may be I'm not a native english). What I understand is you don't want any click event to fire

Comment: It's like this. Assume I hover my mouse on the "Log In" button, the mask appears over the login button. Since the mask has pointerEvents set to 'none', If I perform a click, then the underlying Log In button would receive the click and the form gets submitted. My aim is to prevent the underlying element from receiving only the 'click' (and some other) events, while still retaining the approach you showed me above for the highlight mask.

Comment: Just like our Chrome inspector. When you inspect an element and you click on it, the click doesn't register. Instead, the corresponding element is highlighted in the source tab of the inspector. I want something similar to this.

Comment: @sriramsridharan sorry can't find how to do it :/

Answer (score 11):

You should do this in CSS and not in JS. Use the `:hover` selector

```
.your-class:hover{
    background-color: #205081;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but here, the "your-class" could be anything. Is it possible to add a pseudo selector to all elements in the dom within the body? That would make it work on any screen.

Comment: @sriramsridharan just replace `.you-class` by `*`

Comment: it highlights everything from the tree, what if you want to highlight only the closes element?

Answer (score 2):

I changed the version by @jonatjano, such as

- it takes in account the viewport scrolling
- it is more compact
- it works also pasted in the developer console (beware of confounding iframes btw)

See it [here](https://jsbin.com/jimezomima/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
window.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
    updateMask(e.target);
});

function updateMask(target) {
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("highlight-wrap")
    let hObj
    if (elements.length !== 0) {
        hObj = elements[0]
    } else {
        hObj = document.createElement("div");
        hObj.className = 'highlight-wrap';
        hObj.style.position = 'absolute';
        hObj.style.backgroundColor = '#205081';
        hObj.style.opacity = '0.5';
        hObj.style.cursor = 'default';
        hObj.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(hObj);
    }
    let rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    hObj.style.left = (rect.left + window.scrollX) + "px";
    hObj.style.top = (rect.top + window.scrollY) + "px";
    hObj.style.width = rect.width + "px";
    hObj.style.height = rect.height + "px";

}
```

Comment: Works great. The earlier one had issues related to scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

@LouieAlmeda and @jonatjano are both right, i just want to add that if you don't like the re-arranges the elements on the page, you can add a `border: 1px solid transparent` to elements and then on mouse-over/hover just change the border-color

Comment: This may not work because I don't have control over the web page's source CSS. What you're proposing assumes that I write the target page as well, which I don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
[attribute = value]:hover {
   css declarations;
}
```

and use it on all divs which should have hover effect.

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me, applying the `hover` rule to all `*` elements.

```css
*:hover {
    background-color: #205081 !important;
}
```

The `!important` ensures overwriting backgrounds set on individual HTML nodes. Keep CSS specificity mind, that is that the browser ignores this CSS rule if a similar rule with `!important` is present on the hovered element.

Thanks to Louie, extending his answer.